# Is there a way to read daily resting heart rate from the Google Fit API?

Tags: android, google-fit

The iOS Google Fit app shows Resting Heart Rate as one of it's metrics (I have not seen it in the Android Google Fit app, however). I would like to show Resting Heart Rate in an Android app using Google Fit Data. However, the Android Google Fit API does not seem to present this data.

I have tried a read request both by `DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM` and by aggregating `DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM` and `DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY` as shown here:

```
DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .setTimeRange(startDate.time, endDate.time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build()
```

The summary gives lowest, highest, and average for a particular time range, but not resting heart rate. Is there a way to get the calculated resting heart rate from the Google Fit Android API?

Answer (score 3):

I use the Google Fit API but with Python, so I am unsure if this helps.

I set the scope in the Google API console:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read
```

I then select this datasource to retrieve the resting heart rate (RHR) for that day (or time period):

```
derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm
```

The JSON response is as follows, the RHR is shown in "fpval" key.

```
{
    "minStartTimeNs": "1606262400000000000",
    "maxEndTimeNs": "1606344504000000000",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm",
    "point": [
        {
            "startTimeNanos": "1606320000000000000",
            "endTimeNanos": "1606320000000000000",
            "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm",
            "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm",
            "value": [
                {
                    "fpVal": 64.49201202392578,  <----- RHR
                    "mapVal": []
                }
            ],
            "modifiedTimeMillis": "1606323455964"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, this pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Where did you find this "resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm" ID? I can't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no data type for resting heart rate in the Android API. Using the information shared by Mr L I surmised that `dataSourceId` is constructed from four Android API calls. It appears that `dataSourceId` is composed as follows:

`data source type`:`data type`:`app package name`:`stream name`

which corresponds to:

`derived`:`com.google.heart_rate.bpm`:`com.google.android.gms`:`resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm`

This corresponds to the following [DataSource.Builder()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource.Builder) functions in the Android API:

- [setType](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource.Builder#setType(int)): value passed should be [DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource?hl=en#TYPE_DERIVED)
- [setDataType](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource.Builder#setDataType(com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType)): value passed should be [DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType#TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
- [setAppPackageName](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource.Builder#setAppPackageName(java.lang.String)): value passed should be `"com.google.android.gms"`
- [setStreamName](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataSource.Builder#setStreamName(java.lang.String)): value passed should be `"resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm"`

Here is my solution:

```
DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataSource.Builder()
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .setStreamName("resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm")
            .build())
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(start, end, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
```

Comment: What about Walking Heart Rate and Recovery Heart Rate? Is there a way to calculate that in Google Fit?